# AJAX returning null XML

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax

I am trying to use AJAX for the first time, and I am having a difficult time getting the hang of it. Here is the request code:

```
function requestData(j) {
    var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    xml = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                    post = "";
                    title = "";
                    postdata = xml.getElementsByTagName("post");
                    titledata = xml.getElementsByTagName("title");
                    datedata = xml.getElementsByTagName("date");
                    timedata = xml.getElementsByTagName("time");
                    document.getElementById("post").value = postdata[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    document.getElementById("heading").value = titledata[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    document.getElementById("date").value = datedata[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    document.getElementById("time").value = timedata[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    document.getElementById("id").value = j;
                    document.getElementById("update").value = "true";
                }
            };
        xmlhttp.open("POST","../script/getnewsdata.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("ID=" + j);
        return false;
    }
```

Firebug is telling me that "xml is null" on the line postdata = xml.getElementsByTagName("post"); Which means that xmlhttp.responseXML is null.

This is the server side script:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("wadafw","awfawf","awfsgv");
if(!$db)
{
  die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("afggbare", $db);
$updata = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM News WHERE NewsID='.$_POST['ID']);
$blog = mysql_fetch_array($updata);
$post = $blog['Content'];
$regex = Array('/<br />/', '/<(\/?)(b|i|u)>/', '/<a href="(http://[www.]?\w+)">(\w+)<\/a>/', '/<div class="media"><iframe title="YouTube video player" width="425" height="265" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/(\w+)hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>/', '/<div class="media"><img width="425" src="(http://[www.]?[\w+])" /></div>/');
$regReplace = Array('\r\n', '[$1$2]', '[link=$1]$2[/link]', '[youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1[/youtube]',
                '[img]$1[/img]');
$post = preg_replace($regex, $regReplace, $post);

echo    '<newsItem>
        <title>'.$blog['Heading'].'</title>
        <post>'.$post.'</post>
        <date>'.$blog['time'].'</date>
        <time>'.$blog['time'].'</time>
    </newsItem>';
?>
```

The regex is probably bad... but that's not important right now.

Changed to this... and now getting "function not defined" errors:

```
function requestData(j) {
        $.ajax("../script/getnewsdata.php", {
            data: {ID: j},
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(data, status, jqXHR){
                var xml = jqXHR.responseXML;
                postdata = xml.getElementsByTagName("post");
                titledata = xml.getElementsByTagName("title");
                datedata = xml.getElementsByTagName("date");
                timedata = xml.getElementsByTagName("time");
                document.getElementById("post").value = postdata[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                document.getElementById("heading").value = titledata[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                document.getElementById("date").value = datedata[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                document.getElementById("time").value = timedata[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                document.getElementById("id").value = j;
                document.getElementById("update").value = "true";
            }


        }
    }
```

Okay, found that problem. It was just a typo... hadn't closed the $.ajax() parameter brackets. Now I am not getting errors. But it just doesn't do anything...

Comment: Where's `<?xml version="1.0"?>`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that. It's in now, but I am getting the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to get AJAX running from scratch, I'd recommend using an existing library. jQuery makes this task extremely easy.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
function requestData(j) {
    $.ajax('../script/getnewsdata.php', {
        data: {ID: j},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(data, status, jqXHR){
            // consume data here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: he need to use plugin for that.

Comment: jQuery may make things easier, but it would require me to learn jQuery first... and I don't have time for that.

Comment: I would recommend this approach. XHR object is too inconsistent to be usable from scratch, just use an external library.

Comment: Luke, you don't have to learn jQuery, you only have to learn javascript :)

Comment: Could you give me some idea of where to start with a jQuery implementation? I am looking at the documentation now but it isn't exactly easy to follow.

Comment: Just saw the code, thanks dragon... how do I parse the html and access certain data items?

Comment: I have implemented the jQuery version... but I am now being told that the function is not defined. I have put the jQuery code in the OP.

Comment: Fixed that issue. Just a typo. Now, however, it appears to be successful but it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Luke Use `console.log(data)` in `success` callback to see what the `data` object looks like. Once you have that information, you can easily access the elements you need.

Comment: @dragon I am being told that "The Web Console Logging API (console.log, etc.) has been disabled by a script on this page"... I don't remember disabling it...

Comment: @dragon After putting some breakpoints in the success function with IE's web developer tools, I have found that the function never seems to be called. However, I have seen the request/response logs and I can confirm that the request is sent and the correct XML data is successfully received.

Comment: Found the problem... The version of jQuery I was using was quite old. Updating that fixed this issue. Thanks @dragon!

Answer (score 0):

its need to look somthing like this:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
else
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       document.getElementById("my").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
 xmlhttp.open("POST","page.php,true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlhttp.send("firstname=lolo&lastname=koko");
```

Comment: I'm confused. I am sending the request with xmhttp and then defining xml as xmlhttp.responseXML when the XMLHttpRequest has fired the onreadystatechange event...

Or, at least that's what I thought was going on.

Comment: That's basically the exact code I was using... I think we got it from the same place... w3schools.com.

Thanks, but I am going with the jQuery.